# Can I check and echo get_post_meta() without running the function twice?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to reduce the amount of times `get_post_meta()` is called, whilst still performing a conditional check to see if the value exists before retrieving it?

```
if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'staffQualifications', true)) {
    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'staffQualifications', true);
}
```

This is running the function twice obviously. Is there a way to only run it once and save resources and memory, whilst still only returning the value if it exists?

Comment: Use a [variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php).

Comment: What's more efficient? To store a variable and use memory, or to run the function twice?

Comment: The value returned by the function is the one that uses the memory, not the variable. The variable is just a name in a table. It uses much less space than the data returned by `get_post_meta()` (which already uses memory since it was created by the function). Calling the function twice means running again some code that uses much more resources (time, memory, database queries etc) than a simple name of a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this ? assign to variable and print when condition is true.

**One Single query to check and print if has value**

```
if($qualification = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'staffQualifications', true)) {
    echo $qualification;
}
```

Test scenario, below code will output var_dump if it has value, else nothing will be output.

```
$a = '';
if($a){
    var_dump($a);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know about this, because I'm now storing a variable, will this use up more memory than the original condition that doesn't?

Comment: No it will not use up memory than the original one, because when running the same it checks for action hooks and filters in wp if you go through the code of `get_post_meta`, that cause the memory use.